# reloading asterisk cronjob

Tags: bash, asterisk

I'm trying to create a crontab job that reloads the asterisk config (sip.conf). Running the command manually, works: `/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx "reload"`

manually running the script with executable permissions, does not. my script is just 2 lines

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx "reload"
```

should i just try to run `/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx "reload"` straight from crontab, without actually having a .sh file somewhere?

Comment: Do you see an error? What is not working? Is your script really on two lines or the one line that is in your question?

Comment: Whose crontab are you trying to run this as?  root's?  your user?  the asterisk user?  from `/etc/crontab`? BTW, `reload` doesn't need to be quoted because it's only a single word.

Comment: I'm running this as root.

Answer (score 0):

One line in crontab does not require .sh file, just put it in crontab.

Check root's mailbox for crontab errors(if you not setuped it - most likely it is  /var/spool/mail/root)